# Firebase & Filtering ordering by value/key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in Firebase:

[image]

I would like to retrieve only the dates falling within a given range, and for that I was using the following `return getMealsRefForUser().orderByValue().equalTo("2018-11-17");`, where the reference is `mealsRefForUser= firebaseDatabase.getReference(MEALS_OF).child(user.getUid());`.
However, the filtering does not happen. What am I missing?

EDIT: So, I am always getting the `/mealsOf/<userId>` node, even if I qualify it by `orderByKey().startAt().endAt()`, although my aim is to get a data snapshot that contains a bunch of nodes whose `<year>-<month>-<day>` "tag" is within the given range.

EDIT: What I am trying to achieve is to bind `LiveData` to a query like this:

```
public FirebaseQueryLiveData( Constraints c ) {
    if ( c == null )
        this.query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("/mealsOf")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    else
        this.query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("/mealsOf")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .orderByKey().startAt(c.dayFrom).endAt(c.dayTo);
}
```

But this ends up giving me the entire list, all the same -- regardless of the constraints.
The whole source code of the class:

```
// https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html
public class FirebaseQueryLiveData extends LiveData<DataSnapshot> {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseQueryLiveData";
    private boolean listenerRemovePending= false;
    private final Handler handler= new Handler();

    private final Runnable removeListener= new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            query.removeEventListener(listener);
            listenerRemovePending= false;
        }
    };

    private static final String LOG_TAG= "FirebaseQueryLiveData";

    private final Query query;
    private final InnerValueEventListener listener= new InnerValueEventListener();

    public FirebaseQueryLiveData( Constraints c ) {
        if ( c == null )
            this.query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("/mealsOf")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        else
            this.query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("/mealsOf")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .orderByKey().startAt(c.dayFrom).endAt(c.dayTo);
    }

    public FirebaseQueryLiveData( DatabaseReference ref ) {
        this.query= ref;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActive");
        if ( listenerRemovePending )
            handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener);
        else
            query.addValueEventListener(listener);
        listenerRemovePending= false ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onInactive");
        handler.postDelayed(removeListener,2000);
        listenerRemovePending= true ;
        //query.removeEventListener(listener);
    }

    private class InnerValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( @NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {
            setValue(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled( @NonNull DatabaseError databaseError ) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can not listen to query " + query,databaseError.toException());
        }
    }
}
```

I think I know what is happening. I have this piece in my code:
`viewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this, new CustomViewModelFactory(c))
                .get(MealListViewModel.class);`

It is not firing when I supply new query constraints. Does it mean that I can get only one viewmodelprovider per run of my application?

EDIT: In the above updated image, under the `meals` child of a date I have the division by hours -- e.g. `20` being `8PM` etc. How would I restrict my query from *both* axes -- days *and* hours?
Before I hear (I must admit appropriate) comments that I need to restructure my database schema, I would like to know if that is possible.
Would we need something along the lines of the following?

```
 return await dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${userId}`)
        .orderByKey().startAt(dayFrom).endAt(dayTo)
        .orderByChild("meals")
        .startAt(`${hourFrom}:00`).endAt(`${hourTo}:59`)
```

Or alternatively, should I keep another location such as `duplicate/{userId}/{day}/{hour}` to enable queries such as

```
return await dbroot.ref(`duplicate/${userId}`)
            .orderByKey().startAt(dayFrom).endAt(dayTo)
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt(`${hourFrom}:00`).endAt(`${hourTo}:59`)
```

Comment: ("2018-11-17") is not a value except a name. I suggest changing your database structure.

Comment: check the database rules if it's not returning any data
it has happened with me a lot that i forgot to edit database rules or when i create new node i forget to define the rules

and if it is ruteurning you data then just show a bit more code so that it can be understood whats wrong

Comment: the dates are keys here. why are you ordering by value? it should be orderByKey

Comment: @RezaNasiri: I did try `orderByKey`, same result -- I get the whole bunch instead of the filtered list.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using a query to grab that key. Queries are used if you want a list returned, or if you don't know the exact path you're trying to reach.

As you know the `uid` and the `date` you can query the object directly.

JavaScript:

```
getMealsRefForUser(userId, date) {
  return firebase.database().ref(`/mealsOf/${userId}/${date}`);
}
```

Android:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("mealsOf");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
return root.child(uid).child("2018-11-17");
```

Otherwise if you want to query you should use the `startAt` or `endAt` methods.

JavaScript:

```
getMealsRefForUser(userId, startDate) {
  return firebase.database().ref(`/mealsOf/${userId}`).orderByKey().startAt(startDate);
}
```

Android:

```
return root.orderByKey().startAt("2018-11-17");
```